# i am using a two dimensional array to plot my graph using jquery flot. how can i use threshold to produce two different colors?

Tags: jquery, flot, threshold

The threshold function works fine on a single dimensional array but when I try to implement it on my two dimensional array that I am taking as input, it does not work.

My array: `d4=[{04,300},{10,800},{15,1200}]`

My options for series:

```
var options_current = {
  series: {
    lines: {
      show: true,
      lineWidth: 7,
      steps: true
    },
    points: {
      show: true,
      radius: 4
    },
  },
  xaxis: {
    min: 1,
    max: 30,
    tickFormatter: dayFormatter,
    tickColor: "rgba(255, 255,255, 0)",
    tickDecimals: 0,
    minTickSize: 5
  },
  yaxis: {
    min: 1,
    tickFormatter: dollarFormatter
  },
  grid: {
    hoverable: true,
    clickable: true,
    markings: [{
      xaxis: {
        from: temp_day,
        to: temp_day
      },
      color: '#A4A4A4'
    }],
  },
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what your data looks like?  Curly braces aren't valid syntax for an array.  Also, where in your series or options are you setting the threshold option?

Comment: yes. i was able to fix the issue

Comment: plotting two different colors on the same slider track is not possible as of now. what i did was to make the slider invisible and override a canvas element on top of it. Plotting two different colors on the canvas element works fine but some times it does not respond.